# Is it possible playing remote mp4 with iOS AVPlayer NOT using ffmpeg?

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, udp, streaming, avplayer

In my project I used ffmpeg library for udp-streaming or remote play for mp4 video file.

But usually I also used to use AVPlayer https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/index.html for playing mp4 or phasset.

Would it be possible or someone make it to play remote mp4 video with AVPlayer?

If it is NOT possible, Could you please explain for me why?

Thanks.

**SOLVED**

It is possible as @Andrey mentioned. and I used https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVPlayerDemo/History/History.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010101-RevisionHistory-DontLinkElementID_1 sample code.

Comment: It's totally possible to play remote mp4 with AVPlayer. Just provide a url in the AVPlayer instance. However, I don't understand how you relate ffmpeg to AVPlayer in your question.

Comment: @Andrey Ok, I found it and it really works. In my project I used ffmpeg library to show udp streaming camera preview from server and in video player also. As you know  FFmpeg can decode any codec and at the first time I thought the video from the server can't played with AVPlayer because of codec problem so I implemented it with ffmpeg.

Comment: Great! AVPlayer is very powerful.. so you don't need to mess with a lower level decoding items.

Comment: @Andrey Right. But if someday I need to make a video player which supports several codec then I should use ffmpeg and OpenGL...

Comment: I had to use ffmpeg for encoding of livestream from camera in order to send data to our backend. Never had to use it for actual playback so far.

Comment: @Andrey Yes right. But to make video player for several codec... ffmpeg decoder is maybe the only way that I know to play it especially in iOS.

Comment: I work for a company and we play video from multiple platforms(youtube, vimeo pro, etc), all of our transcoding logic is handled in a backend. What I'm getting in the end is either mp4 video or hls stream, so I have no problem with playing them.

Comment: @Andrey @Hwangho Kim Is `AVPlayer` using `ffmpeg` from lower level?

Comment: @Boris Nope, I don't think so.

Comment: @HwanghoKim, `AVPlayer` is using `VideoToolBox` or `AudioToolBox`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's totally possible to play remote mp4 with AVPlayer. Just provide a url in the AVPlayer instance.